# React native: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

First of all, I found many questions with the same problem, yet none have seemed to help me. The code does reach the `this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')` but after throws the error seen in the title. The documentation states that you can just use `this.props` but it seems to be undefined. I also tried to just use `props.navigation` and even destruct navigation inside the `checkedIfLogginIn` as a parameter like this `checkIfLoggedIn = ({ navigation }) => {}`. Maybe it is a small thing im overseeing but the problem has been me for quiet a while now and I need it fixed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import{ createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoginScreen from './Components/LoginScreen';
import firebase from './firebase';

class App extends Component{

 checkedIfLoggedIn = () => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
   if (user) {
     this.props.navigation.navigate(AppStackNavigator);
   } else {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
   }
  })
 }

 componentDidMount(){
   this.checkedIfLoggedIn();
 }

 render() {
   return < AppContainer />;
 }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate
```

This is only accesible if you are inside one of these:

```
import{ createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation', so p
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

If you want to use it you need to be inside, for example:
You use a onClickfunction as a prop of the tag:

```
<AppNav onClick={nav to ... or call a function to do something}/>
```